# How to Calculate new location with distance and bearing

Tags: android-location

I am wondering if there is a simple way to manually change a `android.location` to be one meter away from a given bearing.

Lets say i have two `locations` and i get the bearing by saying:

```
location1.bearingTo(location2)
```

and i have a static distance traveled of 1 meter..

how would i go about saying:

```
location1 = //1 meter from location1 at bearing
```

I am wondering if there is a built in method for `android.location` that does this.. I looked and didn't see one, but maybe i am just missing it.. or if anyone can point me in the right direction for figuring out the math

Comment: Have a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079536/add-distance-to-a-particular-latitude-longitude-position/20092884#20092884

Comment: Thanks but your answer deals with north south or east west.. I'd like to go strictly by degrees

Comment: The maths is here, note that 6371 is the Earth radius in km... http://www.etechpulse.com/2014/02/calculate-latitude-and-longitude-based.html

Comment: thanks don't know why i couldn't find that..

Answer (score 1):

There are two built-in methods that I know of:

1. Using SphericalUtil:

SphericalUtil.computeOffsetOrigin(startLocation, distance, bearing);

2. Using OsmDroid:

   GeoPoint startLocation = ...;

   startLocation.destinationPoint(distance, bearing);